# Howto use maven in a heterogenous environment with different encodings?

Tags: windows, linux, svn, maven-2, encoding

I've created a svn repositoy on a linux server (Debian) and used a client on a windows machine to check my java sources in.

Now I've set up a Hudson server on a different linux server (Ubuntu) to periodically run tests on my code. But the tests fail with a compiler error:

```
Error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

On my windows machine I've used the default encoding Cp1252. 
On my svn server I can do a local checkout of my sources and they look good.
On my Hudson server the checkout contains illegal characters.

What are the parameters I have to adjust so that all three systems use a working encoding?

**EDIT 2009-10-15:**

I changed the default encoding of my Ubuntu system to `latin1`. Now I can open the checkedout files with an editor and they look good (thanks to @John-T at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/55224/change-the-default-codepage-from-latin1-to-utf8-on-a-linux-machine/55233#55233)).

But Hudson still complained about `unmappable character for encoding ASCII` and I found that this is caused by maven. I found an [explantion](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning), but the suggested solution didn't work. Now maven tells me that it uses `latin1` when copying some resources, but the compiler (not using this setting?) still complains with the same error message.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, the maven compiler plugin doesn't use the `project.build.sourceEncoding` property. So you need to configure the file encoding for it (I'd use UTF-8):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: alternatively, you could use `<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>`

Comment: Since plugin ver 2.0, the default value is: ${project.build.sourceEncoding}.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to identify is which character is causing the problem. It may be that the broken char can be replaced by some pure-ASCII entity. SVN itself is encoding agnostic: it'll just store byte-for-byte what's passed in.

If Hudson requires 7-bit ASCII, then this is all you can do. Otherwise, find out what Hudson supports and save your files in this format instead. UTF-8 would probaby be the way to go.

Comment: I have hundreds of files and I always used german as the language for comments. So it's not reasonable to manually change all occurences.

Comment: See if Hudson accepts one of UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15. And see if you can save your files in one of those formats...

Comment: You can use `iconv` to convert a file from one character set to another, you could script this to convert the files from CP1252 to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change the encoding of a file with SVN.  You can set the encoding for a commit message with the `--encoding` flag, but not the contents of files themselves.  Text files are stored in the same format they appear on your local disk. The only conversion is a translation of line endings according to the svn:eol-style property.